# How to configure Web Api 2 to look for Controllers in a separate project? (just like I used to do in Web Api)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I used to place my controllers into a separate Class Library project in Mvc Web Api. I used to add the following line in my web api project's global.asax to look for controllers in the separate project:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("MyClassLibraryProject.Controllers");
```

I never had to do any other configuration, except for adding the above line. This has always worked fine for me.

However I am unable to use the above method to do the same in WebApi2. It just doesn't work. The WebApi2 project still tries to find the controllers in its own project's controllers folder.

-- Giving little summary update after 2 months (As I started bounty on this):

I have created a WebApiOne solution, it has 2 projects, the first one is WebApi project, and the second is a class library for controllers. If I add the reference to the controllers class library project into the WebApi project, all works as expected. i.e. if i go to http://mydevdomain.com/api/values i can see the correct output.

I have now create a second project called WebApiTwo, it has 2 projects, the first one is WebApi2 project, and the second is a class library for controllers. If I add the reference to the controllers class library project to the WebApi2 project, it doest NOT work as expected. i.e. if i go to http://mydevdomain.com/api/values i get "No type was found that matches the controller named 'values'."

for the first project i am not doing any custom settings at all, i do NOT have:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("MyClassLibraryProject.Controllers");
```

in my global.asax, and i have not implemented any custom solutions proposed by StrathWeb in two of his blog posts, as i think its not applicable any more; because all works just by adding the reference of the controller project to the WebApi project.

So i would expect all to work same for WebApi2 ... but its not. Has anyone really tried doing this in WebAPi2 ?

Comment: The code you are showing is related to MVC controllers which has nothing to do with Web API.  As long as the assembly with your Web API controllers has been loaded the Controllers will be found.

Comment: +1 on what Darrel is mentioning

Comment: This may give you some pointers on what you're trying to do: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @DarrelMiller ... thanks ... that then means it was working in MVC4 and is NOT working in MVC5 ... I have just created two temp projects to demonstrate this, MVC4 with WebApi is definitely working, but MVC5 with WebApi2 is not ...

Comment: WebApi1 and WebApi2 both load controllers from ALL loaded assemblies.  And other than being bundled together in a template, Web API core has zero dependency on MVC.  You need to find out why your controller assembly is not being loaded.

Comment: assemblies are definitely loading. i just did this: var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); and i can see my controllers assemble in there ... cant get this to work in web api2. any other ideas ???

Comment: It's a long shot, but I have to ask - are the controller classes and methods in MyClassLibraryProject.Controllers marked as public?

Comment: This should work out-of-the-box. I have done this a million times. The `Web Api` infrastructure scans all assemblies loaded in the `AppDomain` and adds all classes that inherit from `ApiController` to the controller collection. I think something else is going on.

Comment: So let me get this straight. Your 1st solution was in WebApi v1, and 2nd was in WebApi v2, right? I tried to reproduce the problem using WebApi v2 (vs2013), as per how your mentioned procedure, however, I was able to get a response from my controller.

Answer (score 30):

I have just confirmed that this works fine. Things to check:

**References:** Does your main Web API project reference the external class library?

**Routing:** Have you set up any routes that might interfere with the external controllers?

**Protection Level:** Are the controllers in the external library `public`?

**Inheritance:** Do the controllers in the external library inherit from `ApiController`?

**Versioning:** Are both your Web API project and class library using the same version of the Web API libraries?

If it helps, I can package up my test solution and make it available to you. 
Also, as a point to note, you don't need to tell Web API to find the controllers with the line you added to `Global.asax`, the system finds the controllers automatically provided you have them referenced.

Comment: mine was about Versioning, I had added Odata to my ClassLib via Nuget, and Nuget had installed "Assembly System.Web.Http.OData.dll, v5.7.0.0" but I noticed that my WebSite project was using an older version. So I opened Nuget Manager for WebSite project and updated Odata package. Then it worked. Thx for pointing that out ;)

Comment: @DavidG I know this topic is a bit old, but I would really like to see a sample of it, as I'm trying to archive something similar, with Controllers in seperated projects, tho my solution rely on a OWIN self-host and not ASP.NET IIS.

Comment: @grmihel On IIS, I literally just had to add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (incl. dependencies Client/Core/WebHost) NuGet package to the library and create a public class that inherits from ApiController. Worked fine, to my surprise. I don't know about OWIN, though. Are you sure your RouteConfig is right?

Answer (score 15):

It should work as is. Checklist

- Inherit `ApiController`
- End controller name with *Controller*. E.g. `ValuesController`
- Make sure WebApi project and class library project reference same WebApi assemblies
- Try to force routes using attribute routing
- `Clean` the solution, manually remove `bin` folders and rebuild
- Delete `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folders. WebApi and MVC cache controller lookup result
- Call `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); to ensure framework takes attribute routes into consideration
- Make sure that the method you are calling is made to handle correct HTTP Verb (if it is a GET web method, you can call via browser URL, if it is POST you have to otherwise craft a web request)

This controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("MyValues")]
public class AbcController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Get")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Ok!";
    }
}
```

matches this url:

`http://localhost/MyValues/Get` (note there is no `/api/` in route because it wasn't specified in `RoutePrefix`.

---

Controller lookup caching:
[This is default controller resolver](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.cs). You will see in the source code that it caches lookup result.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a list of controllers available for the application.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>An <see cref="ICollection{Type}" /> of controllers.</returns>
public override ICollection<Type> GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
{
    HttpControllerTypeCacheSerializer serializer = new HttpControllerTypeCacheSerializer();

    // First, try reading from the cache on disk
    List<Type> matchingTypes = ReadTypesFromCache(TypeCacheName, IsControllerTypePredicate, serializer);
    if (matchingTypes != null)
    {
        return matchingTypes;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Why does the class name has to end with Controller? Why isn't it enough to inherit from ApiController?

Comment: For me, while trying to set up a route like `/api/cars`, a controller in an external assembly called CarApiController and decorated with `[RoutePrefix("/api/cars")]` did not work, but just changing the class name to `CarsController` made it work. Odd, but maybe someone can explain that.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja Did you make this work with WebApi 2? I'm struggling badly while I'm trying to seperate controller into it's own project, and having a console project that should consume this controller project, but what I get is: {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:9000/api/values/5'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'values'."} using OWIN self-host

Comment: @grmihel: Checklist should work for WebApi 2 as well. I added last two items now.

Comment: @grmihel it should just work. MVC/Web API 2 only require the controller to be loaded in the app domain for the controller to be routed to, once the route itself has been defined. Are you sure you are hitting the end point with the right verb? Try using Postman. You can choose the HTTP verb in there. I am certain that's why you can't find the endpoint. If you want me to look, put your code in a repository on Bitbucket or Github and let me have the link to it.

Answer (score 10):

Was running into same scenario and @justmara set me on the right path.  Here's *how* to accomplish the force loading of the dependent assemblies from @justmara's answer:

1)  Override the DefaultAssembliesResolver class

```
public class MyNewAssembliesResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {

        ICollection<Assembly> baseAssemblies = base.GetAssemblies();
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(baseAssemblies);
        var controllersAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Path_to_Controller_DLL");
        baseAssemblies.Add(controllersAssembly);
        return baseAssemblies;

    }
}
```

2) In the configuration section, replace the default with the new implementation

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new MyNewAssembliesResolver());
```

I cobbled this syntax together using pointers from this blog:

http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/

As others have said, you know if you are running into this issue if you force the controller to load by directly referencing it.  Another way is to example the results of `CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` and see if your assembly is in the list.

Also:  If you are self-hosting using OWIN components you WILL run into this.  When testing keep in mind that the DefaultAssembliesResolver will NOT kick in until the first WebAPI request is submitted (it took me awhile to realize that).

Comment: Do you need the line List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(baseAssemblies); ? It doesn't look like assemblies does anything.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the method be public override instead of public virtual?

Comment: Unfortunately, the original code you refer to contains typos, and your version is also not correct. It will _not_ behave as expected unless you correct the signature (`virtual` -> `override`). If you do that, the code will work, but as pointed out before, `assemblies` is not used. Delete that assignment, or correct the usage, i.e. change the call to `baseAssemblies.Add` into `assemblies.Add` and then return `assemblies`, not `baseAssemblies`.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure that your referenced assembly was loaded BEFORE IAssembliesResolver service called?
Try to insert some dummy code in your application, something like

`var a = new MyClassLibraryProject.Controllers.MyClass();`

in configuration method (but don`t forget, that compiler can "optimize" this code and totally remove it, if "a" is never used).
I've had similar issue with assembly loading order. Ended up with force loading dependent assemblies on startup.

Answer (score 6):

You need to tell webapi/mvc to load your referrenced assembly.  You do that with the compilation/assemblies section in your web.config.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="XYZ.SomeAssembly" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Simple as that.  You can do it with code the way @user1821052 suggested, but this web.config version will have the same effect.

Comment: Adding on: I prefer doing it this way because you don't have to recompile any code to add or remove loaded assemblies.  This get's read and processed during Application Initialization (before it fires) so will only happen once per application pool lifetime.

Comment: I had to do one more thing apart from adding assembly to web.config. Since I had no other usage of additional assembly from main assembly, I had add a reference with Copy Local = True.

Comment: Yeah, Copy Local = True means the reference will copy itself to the bin folder when you build.  The dll has to be in the Bin folder for it to get picked up by the .net loader when the app pool loads.

By default, new references should always have copy local = true set unless you set it to false previously for some reason.

Comment: My comment wasn't so much about Copy Local=True. But, that I needed to add a reference to the main project.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what has been said already:

*Make sure you don't have two controllers of the same name in different namespaces.*

Just had the case where one controller (foo.UserApiController) should be partially migrated to a new namespace (bar.UserApiController) and URI. The old controller was mapped by convention to /userapi, the new one was attribute-routed via `RoutePrefix["api/users"]`. The new controller didn't work until I renamed it to bar.UserFooApiController.

Answer (score 1):

When using AttributeRouting it is easily forgettable to decorate your methods with the `Route` Attribute, especially when you are using the `RoutePrefix` Attribute on your controller class. It seems like your controller assembly wasn't picked up by the web api pipeline then.

Answer (score 0):

If your class library is built with `EF` then make sure you have the connection string specified in the `App.config` for the class library project, ***AND*** in the `Web.config` for your Web API `MVC` project.