# Can I use an ApiController from external DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing a WebAPI using ASP.Net.

One project is the main, that have its own `ApiController`.

The second project also have an `ApiController`.

When does the `ApiController`s register to wait the request, so I can force it to load the external controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Web Api 2 to look for Controllers in a separate project? (just like I used to do in Web Api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493707/how-to-configure-web-api-2-to-look-for-controllers-in-a-separate-project-just/23940559#23940559)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know, I have dupe hammer but am reluctant to hammer to a question where I have the top answer.

Comment: @DavidG Does that work for DLLs loaded dinamically?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: The [third](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31619351/2141621) answer explains how to do this for dynamic assemblies

Comment: The external DLL will be dynamically loaded, after the main dll runs.
A method will iterate through the DLLs of a folder and load them

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried using the third answer, but I don't know how does the `AssembliesResolver` find the `ApiController` using only the assembly.