# WebAPI cannot find route to controller if derived in referenced library

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a custom library and I am now creating a new application that uses this library. In most projects using this library, we are using WebAPI with authentication, so in that library we have a custom class `ApiControllerBase` that has all the fancy stuff we need in our controllers.

And in all projects so far, controller classes derive from that `ApiControllerBase`:

```
public class LoginController : ApiControllerBase
{
```

with the `ApiControllerBase` deriving from `ApiController`:

```
abstract public class ApiControllerBase : ApiController
{
```

and the route finds the controller.

In the new app I created today, this does not work:

```
public class ExampleController : ApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public bool GetTrue()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

causes the error

```
<Error>
<Message>
Es wurde keine HTTP-Ressource gefunden, die mit dem Anforderungs-URI "http://localhost:50467/api/Example" übereinstimmt.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
Es wurde kein Typ gefunden, der mit dem Controller namens "Example" übereinstimmt.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

while

```
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public bool GetTrue()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

correctly results in

```
<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>
```

If I create a new `ApiControllerBaseLocal` in the new project itself:

```
abstract public class ApiControllerBaseLocal :ApiController
{
```

and reference that instead, it also works correctly; so I suspect something like a type clash (maybe Reflection doesn't think that the type `ApiController` in the library is the same as the type `ApiController` in the project). I have already checked that all projects and the library use the same .NET version (4.5.2), the new is no exception.

What am I possibly missing here?

Comment: Dubbelcheck with this list https://stackoverflow.com/a/23943207

Comment: @MarcusHöglund I have checked everything, most of it was straightforward but did not fix it. Regarding "Make sure WebApi project and class library project reference same WebApi assemblies"? Which references would I have to check? System.Net, System.Net.Http, anything else?

Comment: I don't know what assembly..guess the bin folder would show if it's more than one certain assembly..One other thing could be the naming of the ApiControllerBase, change it to ApiBaseController.. Sounds like the suffix needs to be *Controller, but that don't explain why it works when you declare the class in your web project..

Comment: @MarcusHöglund If I understand correctly, the actual Controllers have to derive from `ApiController` and end in `...Controller`, but the naming of intermediate classes in the class hierarchy can be completely arbitrary.