# How to use Area(in MVC) in different Solutions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-areas

I created an area named `Hello` in a solution named `XYZ`. I then created a nuget package from this solution and referenced it into my solution named `ABC`.
Now I'm facing issue with routing or I even might be missing something. 
I would need a solution for .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: you would need to add code to tell the main project to scan for controllers in another project. beyond the capability of most....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493707/how-to-configure-web-api-2-to-look-for-controllers-in-a-separate-project-just

Comment: Create a Razor Class Library (RCL), put your area and any other shared views, static files, etc. in there. Package it as a NuGet, and then add package references to that NuGet in your other solution projects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create "Razor Library" to create reusable UI components same like "Identity" system.

See the MSDN [Create reusable UI using the Razor class library project in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and [ASP.NET Core Razor components class libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.0).